# Adjoint of Volterra type operator

Tags: functional-analysis

I have the following problem in my lecture notes on functional analysis which I can't seem to figure out:

Define $$ H = \{ f\in L^2([0,2\pi]) | \int_0^{2\pi}f(x)dx = 0 \}. $$ Define the operator $T$ by the formula $$(Tf)(x) = i \int_0^x f(y)dy + \frac{i}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}yf(y)dy.$$ Prove that $T$ is a compact self-adjoint operator on $H$.

My idea was to write $T$ as $T = iV + \frac{i}{2\pi} \mathcal{I}$ where $V$ is the Volterra operator and $\mathcal{I}$ the integral operator with kernel $K(x,y)=y$. The compactness follows then from the fact that integral operators are compact and the sum of compact operators is compact. For the adjoint we get $T^* = -iV^* - \frac{i}{2\pi} \mathcal{I}^* $. I know what the adjoint is of the Volterra operator and the adjoint of $\mathcal{I}$ is the integral operator with kernel $K(x,y)^* = \overline{K(y,x)} = x$. My question is why $\mathcal{I}^* $ is not identically $0$? If it is identical zero however, how come $T$ is self-adjoint since for this $H$ we have $V^* = -V$?

Comment: Doesn't $\mathcal I^{*}=0$ mean $\mathcal I=0$?

Comment: Yes and $\mathcal{I}$ is clearly not $0$ but if I write out the formula for $\mathcal{I}^*$ I get that it is always zero since it is the integral from $0$ to $2\pi$ of a function from $H$.

Comment: The problem seems to be that the two terms in the definition of $Tf$ are not operators from $H$ into itslef.  So you cannot deal with the two terms separately.

Comment: I also thought that that was the problem but when you try to calculate the adjoint directly with $T$ then it comes down to calculating the adjoint of $V$ and $\mathcal{I}$ because of the linearity of the integral, i.e. $$ \langle Tf,g\rangle = \int_0^{2\pi}\left(i\int_0^xf(y)dy+\frac{i}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} yf(y)dy\right)\overline{g(x)}dx$$ and this thing splits into the parts I mentioned in the post (I think).

Comment: Self-adjointness of a bounded operator  is equivalent to $\langle Tf,f\rangle =\langle f,Tf\rangle,$ or  $\langle Tf,g\rangle= \langle f, Tg\rangle,$ where $f,g\in H.$ You have to use the property $\int f=\int g=0.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The properties of the linear operator $T: H \to H$ can easily be studied *without* taking the detour via the larger Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}:= L^2([0,2\pi]) \supset H$.

First of all, you have to check that $Tf \in H$ $\, \forall f \in H$. This is indeed the case, as
$$\begin{align}  \int\limits_0^{2\pi} (Tf)(x) dx &=  i\int\limits_0^{2\pi} \left(\int\limits_0^xf(y) dy+ \frac{1}{2\pi}\int\limits_0^{2\pi} yf(y) dy     \right)dx  \\ &=i\int\limits_0^{2\pi}(2\pi-y)f(y) dy+ i\int\limits_0^{2\pi}yf(y) dy \\&=2\pi i \int\limits_0^{2\pi}f(y)dy=0    \end{align} \tag{1} \label{eq1}      $$ for $f \in H$. As already remarked in a comment by @geetha290krm, it is important to note that the two individual terms  $g_1(x)=i \int_0^{x} f(y) dy$ and $g_2(x)=(i/2\pi)\int_0^{2\pi} y f(y) dy$ are, in general, *not* elements of $H$, but only their sum fulfills the requirement $\int_0^{2\pi} \! \! \left(g_1(x)+g_2(x)\right) dx=0$.

The self-adjointness of $T$ is checked by starting from the expression (see the comment by @RyszardSzwarc) $$ \begin{align} \langle Tf |g\rangle &= \int\limits_0^{2\pi} \! (Tf)(y) \, \overline{g(y)} \, dy \\ &= i \int\limits_0^{2\pi} \! {\huge(} \int\limits_0^y \! f(x) dx {\huge)}    \overline{g(y)}\,  dy+\frac{i}{2\pi} \int\limits_0^{2\pi} \!xf(x) dx \underbrace{\int\limits_0^{2\pi} \!\overline{g(y)} dy}_{=0} \\&= i\int\limits_0^{2\pi} \! f(x) {\huge(} \int\limits_x^{2\pi} \! \overline{g(y)}\, dy    {\huge)} dx  \\ &=  i \int\limits_0^{2\pi} f(x) {\huge(} \underbrace{\int\limits_0^{2\pi} \!\overline{g(y)}\,  dy}_{=0}- \int\limits_0^x \! \overline{g(y)} dy    {\huge)} dx    \\ &= \int\limits_0^{2\pi}f(x){\huge(} \int\limits_0^x \overline{i g(y) } dy {\huge)}dx  \\ &= \int\limits_0^{2\pi} f(x)  {\huge(} \int\limits_0^x \overline{i g(y)} dy +  \int\limits_0^{2\pi} \overline{(i/2\pi) y g(y)} dy {\huge)} dx  \\ &=\langle f |Tg\rangle      \end{align} \tag{2} \label{eq2}$$ for $f,g \in H$.

The eigenvalue problem $T\phi = \lambda \phi$ for $\phi \in H$ and $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ can be solved by finding the solutions of the differential equation $$ i \phi(x) = \lambda \phi^\prime(x), \qquad \tag{3} \label{eq3} \int\limits_0^{2\pi}\! \phi(x) dx =0, $$ leading to the complete orthonormal system of eigenfunctions
$$ \phi_n(x) = \frac{e^{i n x}}{\sqrt{2}\pi}, \quad n \in \mathbb{Z}\setminus \{0\} \tag{4} \label{eq4} $$
with associated eigenvalues $\lambda_n =1/n$. Employing the notation $(\psi \otimes \phi^\ast) f = \psi \langle f | \phi \rangle$, the spectral decomposition of $T$ is thus given by
$$T= \sum\limits_{n\in \mathbb{Z} \setminus \{0\}} \frac{1}{n} \, \phi_n \otimes \phi_n^\ast, \tag{5} \label{eq5}$$
reflecting the well-known properties of a self-adjoint compact operator.

As a little exercise in self torture, let us finally discuss the operator $T:H\to H$ regarded as the restriction $T= \mathcal{T}|_H$ of some appropriately chosen linear operator $\mathcal{T}: \mathcal{H} \to \mathcal{H}$ on the Hilbert space
$$\mathcal{H} = L^2([0,2\pi]) = H \oplus H^\perp, \tag{6} \label{eq6}$$
where $H^\perp$ is nothing else than the one-dimensional subspace spanned by the constant function $\alpha(x) :=1 \in \mathcal{H}$. The Volterra operator $\mathcal{V} : \mathcal{H} \to \mathcal{H}$, defined by
$$(\mathcal{V} f)(x)= \int_0^x \! \! f(y) dy, \quad f \in \mathcal{H}, \tag{7} \label{eq7}$$
and the operator $\mathcal{I}: \mathcal{H} \to \mathcal{H},$ with $$(\mathcal{I} f)(x) = \int_0^{2\pi} \! \! y f(y) dy, \quad f \in \mathcal{H}, \tag{8} \label{eq8}$$ are now perfectly well defined on the larger Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$. The associated adjoint operators are given by
$$\begin{align} (\mathcal{V}^\ast f)(x) &= \int\limits_x^{2\pi} \! \! f(y) dy = \int\limits_0^{2\pi}\! \! f(y) dy - (\mathcal{V}f)(x), \tag{9} \label{eq9} \\ (\mathcal{I}^\ast f)(x) &= x \int\limits_0^{2\pi} \! \! f(y) dy.  \tag{10}\label{eq10} \end{align} $$
Introducing $\beta(x) := x \in \mathcal{H}$, eqs. \eqref{eq7}, \eqref{eq9} and \eqref{eq10} can be written in the compact form
$$\mathcal{I} = \alpha \otimes \beta^\ast, \quad \mathcal{V}^\ast = \alpha \otimes \alpha^\ast - \mathcal{V}, \quad \mathcal{I}^\ast = \beta \otimes \alpha^\ast. \tag{11} \label{eq11}$$

Following your suggestion, let us now try the operator
$${\mathcal{T}^\prime}= i\mathcal{V} +\frac{i}{2\pi} \mathcal{I}, \tag{12} \label{eq12}$$ where $T= \mathcal{T}^\prime|_H$. The subspace $H$ is obviously invariant under $\mathcal{T}^\prime$, but $H^\perp$ is not. Using \eqref{eq11}, we find
$$ (\mathcal{T}^\prime)^\ast = \mathcal{T}^\prime - i \alpha \otimes \alpha^\ast - \frac{i}{2\pi} \left(\alpha \otimes \beta^\ast + \beta \otimes \alpha^\ast \right), \tag{13} \label{eq13}$$ i.e. $\mathcal{T}^\prime$ fails to be self-adjoint. However, finding a self-adjoint extension of $T$ is now easy. As the orthogonal projectors on $H^\perp$ and $H$ are given by $$\mathcal{P} = \frac{1}{2\pi}\alpha \otimes \alpha^\ast \quad \text{and} \quad \mathcal{Q} = {\rm id}_\mathcal{H} -\mathcal{P}, \tag{14} \label{eq14}$$ we define $$\mathcal{T} = \mathcal{Q} \mathcal{T}^\prime \mathcal{Q}, \tag{15} \label{eq15}$$ having the desired properties $$ T = \mathcal{T}|_\mathcal{H} \quad \text{and} \quad \mathcal{T}^\ast = \mathcal{T}, \tag{16} \label{eq16}$$ as $$\mathcal{T}^\ast =(\mathcal{Q} \mathcal{T}^\prime \mathcal{Q})^\ast=\mathcal{Q} (\mathcal{T}^\prime)^\ast \mathcal{Q} = \mathcal{Q} \mathcal{T}^\prime \mathcal{Q} = \mathcal{T}, \tag{17} \label{eq17}$$ where \eqref{eq13} together with $\mathcal{Q} \alpha \otimes \alpha^\ast = \mathcal{Q} \alpha \otimes \beta^\ast = \beta \otimes \alpha^ \ast \mathcal{Q} =0$ were used. In addition to the eigenfunctions already given in \eqref{eq4}, the operator $\mathcal{T}$ has the additional (normalized) eigenvector $\phi_0=\alpha/\sqrt{2 \pi}$ with associated eigenvalue $0$.